python API: how to debug error message which maybe originates in the jpype glue code, or the JVM?
I am trying to port an OptaPy Problem to Timefold/Python.
Now I am stuck with an error message which does not seem related to the referenced LOC, but maybe to something within the JVM. I seem unable to turn on DEBUG logging for "timefold.solver", so far.
Any pointers on how to diagnose this?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/***/git/optapy-pplan/optapy-test/src/main2.py", line 426, in <module>
    solution = solver.solve(generate_problem(sservice.context._inputfile))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/***/.virtualenvs/timefold/lib/python3.11/site-packages/timefold/solver/_solver.py", line 109, in solve
    java_solution = self._delegate.solve(java_problem)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'ai.timefold.jpyinterpreter.types.PythonString'

Edit1 (domain objects):
The domain objects are derived from the school-scheduling example of Optapy. I have reduced the number of methods somewhat, for brevity.
class RoomGroup:
    id : Annotated[int, PlanningId]
    size : int
    
    def __init__(self, group):
        if group==None:
            # a NoneRoom, which does not create conflict
            self.id = 0
            self.name = "None"
            self.group = []
            self.size = 65535
            self.rooms = 0
            self.penalty = 0
            self.nextMinSize = 0
        else:
            self.id = reduce(lambda x,y: x+2**y.id, group, 0)
            self.name = ",".join([room.name for room in group])
            self.group = group 
            self.size = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y.size, group, 0)
            self.rooms = len(self.group)
            self.penalty = 0
            # the next smaller size of this group (remove smallest room)
            self.nextMinSize = self.size - min([r.size for r in group])
        
    def get_id(self) -> int:
        return self.id
    
    
    def equalGroup(self, other):
        return self.id == other.get_id() # encoding! nice!

    def __str__(self):
        return f"RoomGroup(id={self.id}, name={self.name} {self.size}P)"


class Timeslot:
    id : Annotated[int, PlanningId]    
    grain:datetime.timedelta=None
    time_max=datetime.time.max
    
    def __init__(self, ident, start_time, end_time):
        self.id = ident
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.end_time = end_time
        self.day_of_week = start_time.weekday()

    def theGrain(self) -> datetime.timedelta: return self.grain
    def theTimeMax(self) -> datetime.time: return self.time_max

    def get_id(self) -> int:
        return self.id
    
    def matches(self, dt : datetime.datetime):
        return self.start_time <= dt and dt < self.end_time
        

    def __str__(self):
        return (
                f"Timeslot("
                f"id={self.id}, "
                f"wd={self.day_of_week}, "
                f"start_time={self.start_time}, "
                f"end_time={self.end_time})"
        )


@planning_entity
class Exam:
    id : Annotated[int, PlanningId]
    pinned : Annotated[bool, PlanningPin]
    timeslot_orig_id : Optional[int]
    sem : dict[str,Set[int]]
    key : List[str]
    student_group : Optional[Set[str]]
    timeslot : Annotated[Timeslot | None, PlanningVariable] = field(default=None)
    timeslots : int = field(default=1)
    timeslot_orig : Optional[Timeslot] = field(default=None)
    room : Annotated[RoomGroup | None, PlanningVariable] = field(default=None)
#    exam_list : List[Self]
    
    def __init__(self, ident, subject, teacher, student_group : Set[str], 
                 timeslot=None, timeslot_orig=None, room=None, participants=0, room_list=None, 
                 timeslots=1):
        self.id = ident
        self.key = []
        self.subject = subject
        self.teacher = teacher
        self.student_group = student_group
        self.sem = dict()
        self.timeslot = timeslot
        self.timeslots = timeslots
        self.timeslot_orig = timeslot_orig
        self.timeslot_orig_id = timeslot_orig.get_id() if timeslot_orig else None
        self.room = room
        self.participants = participants
        self.room_list = [] if room_list==None else room_list 
        self.pinned = False
        self.exam_list = []
        
    def __hash__(self): return super(Exam, self).__hash__()

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def get_timeslot(self)->Optional[Timeslot]:
        return self.timeslot

    def set_timeslot(self, new_timeslot:Timeslot):
        self.timeslot = new_timeslot

    def get_room(self) -> Optional[RoomGroup]:
        return self.room
    
    def is_moved(self) -> bool:
        return ( self.timeslot != None and self.timeslot_orig_id != None 
                and (self.timeslot.get_id() != self.timeslot_orig_id))

    def is_moved_dist(self) -> int:
        if self.is_moved():
            return (self.timeslot.get_id() - self.timeslot_orig_id)
        else:
            return 0
        
    def is_moved_days(self) -> int:
        if self.is_moved():
            return (self.timeslot.start_time.date() - self.timeslot_orig.start_time.date()).days
        else:
            return 0
    
    def is_pinned(self)->bool:
        return self.pinned

    def set_room(self, new_room:RoomGroup):
        self.room = new_room

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f"Exam("
            f"id={self.id}, "
            f"timeslot={self.timeslot}, "
            f"timeslot_orig_id={self.timeslot_orig_id}, "
            f"room={self.room}, "
            f"rooms={','.join([str(r.id) for r in self.room_list])}, "
            f"teacher={self.teacher}, "
            f"subject={self.subject}, "
            f"student_group={self.student_group}, "
            f"sem={self.sem}, "
            f"participants={self.participants}"
            f")"
        )


def format_list(a_list):
    return ',\n'.join(map(str, a_list))

@planning_solution
class TimeTable:
    lesson_list : Annotated[list[Exam], PlanningEntityCollectionProperty]
    timeslot_list : Annotated[list[Timeslot], ProblemFactCollectionProperty, ValueRangeProvider]
    room_list : Annotated[list[RoomGroup], ProblemFactCollectionProperty, ValueRangeProvider]
    score: Annotated[HardSoftScore, PlanningScore] = field(default=None)
    solver_status: Annotated[SolverStatus, Field] = field(default=SolverStatus.NOT_SOLVING)

    
    def __init__(self, timeslot_list, room_list, lesson_list, score=None):
        self.timeslot_list = timeslot_list
        self.room_list = room_list
        self.lesson_list = lesson_list
        self.score = score

    def __hash__(self): return super(TimeTable, self).__hash__()

    def get_timeslot_list(self):
        return self.timeslot_list

    def get_room_list(self):
        return self.room_list
    
    def get_lesson_list(self):
        return self.lesson_list

    def get_score(self):
        return self.score

    def set_score(self, score):
        self.score = score

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f"TimeTable("
            f"timeslot_list={format_list(self.timeslot_list)},\n"
            f"room_list={format_list(self.room_list)},\n"
            f"lesson_list={format_list(self.lesson_list)},\n"
            f"score={str(self.score) if self.score is not None else 'None'}"
            f")"
        )    


While posting this I became suspicious about the format_list function. I will test this. However, it would be nice to have better targeted debug messages out of the JVM, if this is possible at all.
Edit 2:
I have removed the format_list function calls - no change. I have raised the level of logging from DEBUG to INFO - no change.
The generate_problem() is too big to post here - it deals with a lot of JSON data extraction and interpretation. However, it is my impression that some python code gets translated to JVM bytecode without a proper mapping of this PythonString class, IMHO.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Can you post your domain objects (that is, the type that generate_problem returns and the classes it references)? Also, is there any C-Native code such as NumPy involved?

@ChristopherChianelli edited. No Numpy or other specialties involved.

There a number of issues in your domain:

Using field without being decorated with @dataclasses.dataclass
Annotating with Field without being a Pydantic model

The domain objects do not need to be a dataclass or Pydantic model, but if they are not, they should use field or Field. When I tried generating a simple problem from this domain (with field + Field removed), no error occured. As for the TypeError, my guess is either your domain typing do not match what they actually are, or generate_problem generates an invalid instance.

As for debug, this exception happened from Java calling Python, and then Python raising an error. Due to https://github.com/jpype-project/jpype/issues/1047 ; the cause get lost in the process. If it happened in Java, the cause would actually be kept.

@ChristopherChianelli Thanks for taking a look. I have removed the Field annotations (relation to dataclass was unknown). What puzzles me is 1) something changed between OptaPy and timefold_python which causes this to break (of course the class/variable decorators are completely different), 2) the generate_problem function is executed in CPython, it adds some strings to variables in the domain classes - I do not immediately see potential hazards there. Unless the timefold decorators ("@planning_entity") are causing code to be translated to the JVM, even before generate_problem is executed.

I recommend starting from scratch; the API completely changed between Timefold and OptaPy. One major difference is OptaPy replaces the Python class with the Java class, which does not happen with Timefold. The other major difference is the use of Annotated to define planning variables instead of decorating getters/setters. https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/tree/stable/python/school-timetabling is the Timefold quickstart for school timetabling.

@ChristopherChianelli I have used the hello_world+school_timetable examples as guidance when transforming my model. Therefore the mistake with 'field'.
The generate_problem(),e.g. optimizes scheduling by replacing formal Exams which take place concurrently and at the same location by a single one and a sum of participants. If Timefold does not replace Python classes by Java, how can I possibly copy a Java *.PythonString into a Python class, before even instantiating the Solution the first time? BTW: is it possible, that this is an issue in the constraints, and not in the domain?

@ChristopherChianelli The error originates in my define_constraints(). I will try to pinpoint this now. Thank you very much for taking the time to comment, here.

It looks like you're encountering a TypeError related to the types of objects being passed to your solver, specifically involving a Java interoperation issue with Python objects

As I do not knowingly use 'ai.timefold.jpyinterpreter.types.PythonString', but python strings, it remains unclear if a part of my model is the cause or the translation layer to the JVM. Therefore my question is about diagnostic options.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
